# What is difference between MainLayout.razor and _layout.cshtml in Pages folder and _layout.cshtml in Pages\Shared folder in blazor server side?

Tags: blazor

I use blazor server side whit visual studio 2022.
I use MainLayout.razor as the default layout. but I dont understand what is _layout.cshtml in Pages folder and Pages\Shared folder use?
Thanks.

Comment: The _layout.cshtml is for ASP.NET MVC pages I think you don't need it for Blazor

Comment: When you mean "in Areas\Identity\Pages\Shared" you should spell that out.

Answer (score 4):

In .Net 6 Blazor project

MainLayout.razor :

- MainLayout is used for default layout which is render in all blazor component, if we want to render other layout in some pages that time we need to specify layout.
- MainLayout is used for set common content in single page

  ```
  @layout EmptyLayout
  ```

as above we need to declare layout for specific components.

_Layout.cshtml:

- Lower version of .Net 6 in Blazor we have _host.cshtml file in blazor project but in .Net 6 we have _layout and _host both file , as below _layout file is call from _host.
- Here is the code of _host.cshml

```
@namespace admin_app.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
```

- Lower version of .Net6 these content set inside _host file, now _layout file is used for declare common css, js and common content which are used in all whole website.
- We also create javascript function inside our _layout file.

Answer (score 3):

- `_Layout.cshtml` renders `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>`.
- `MainLayout.razor` renders extra `<body>` content.